# How can I implement dilated convolution in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use dilated convolution in Keras. I found `AtrousConv2D` but could not find any definition for it in the Keras docs and when I use

```
acov=AtrousConv2D((3,3))(image)
```

it produces this error

> **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kernel_size'

I need dilation convolution but I do not know how can I use this layer or how can I produce this layer  myself.

Comment: Made question clearer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard keras [Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) layer supports dilation, you just need to set the `dilation_rate` to a value bigger than one. For example:

```
out = Conv2D(10, (3, 3), dilation_rate=2)(input_tensor)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. can I use padding='same' for this or not? the size of output is the same as regular conv layer ( w-k+2p/s +1)?